# mvc4 apply javascript function to input

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Am trying to apply a function to a dropdownlist in my MVC4 form. However the "'"s around the variables keep rendering in the HTML as "&#39". Obviously for javascript this is not what I what. Am currently using the following code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(t => t.tabPosition, new SelectList(ViewBag.DdlPositions), new { onclick = Html.Raw("ddlChain(this.id, '" + Html.DisplayNameFor(t => t.relTab) + "', '')") })
```

and the html produced looks like

```
<select id="tabPosition" name="tabPosition" onclick="ddlChain(this.id, &#39;relTab, &#39;&#39;)">
<option>Start</option>
<option>End</option>
<option>Before</option>
<option>After</option>
</select>
```

Alternatively is there a better way of assigning a js function to an input in MVC?

Thanks

Comment: The browser should process the entities before parsing the JS; your code should work fine.

Comment: However, it's better to add the handler in JS code and avoid event handler attributes.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Comment: And moreover this onclick="ddlChain(this.id, &#39;relTab, &#39;&#39;)"

here &#39;relTab and &#39;&#39; should be in single quote.

Answer (score 0):

it is also better to pass the list through the model instead of through ViewBag.  Going along with @SLaks answer put this in your script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tabPosition').on('change', function(){
        //Your code here for the change event something like
        $('.Selected').val($('#tabPosition :selected').val());
        //which will set an field on your page with class="Selected" to the selected item from your dropdown
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the first part of your code to this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(t => t.tabPosition, new SelectList(ViewBag.DdlPositions), new Dictionary<string,string>{{ "data-tab", Model.relTab }})
```

The `select element` is created with an `data-tab` attribute.

Now, we just need to create a javascript to read the `data-tab` value and call your `ddlChain` function.

```
$('#tabPosition').on('change', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    ddlChain($this.attr('id'), $this.attr('data-tab'), ''); 
});
```